# JIRA : Webpage Keeps loading on initial database setup?

Tags: java, jira, jira-agile

I just Installed & Configured the JIRA application on my local server..when Accessing to the Page http://************:8080/secure/SetupDatabase.jspa its keep on loading and doesn't go further

And I checked the Tomcat log,

I found the below error,

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
ng bean with name 'ao': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested e
xception is org.springframework.osgi.service.ServiceUnavailableException: servic
e matching filter=[(objectClass=com.atlassian.activeobjects.external.ActiveObjec
ts)] unavailable
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport$
1.run(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:127)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.
doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:116)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.
getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:91)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObje
ctForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:217)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:671)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolve
AutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createA
rgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:584)
        ... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.osgi.service.ServiceUnavailableException: service
 matching filter=[(objectClass=com.atlassian.activeobjects.external.ActiveObject
s)] unavailable
        at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.Servic
eDynamicInterceptor.getTarget(ServiceDynamicInterceptor.java:419)
        at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.Servic
eDynamicInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(ServiceDynamicInterceptor.java:472)
        at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.OsgiServiceProxyFac
toryBean.createProxy(OsgiServiceProxyFactoryBean.java:215)
        at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.AbstractServiceImpo
rterProxyFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractServiceImporterProxyFactoryBean.java:86)
        at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.OsgiServiceProxyFac
toryBean.getObject(OsgiServiceProxyFactoryBean.java:161)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport$
1.run(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:121)
        ... 49 more
```

Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: What version of JIRA? Does your Java version match the system requirements for the version of JIRA you are using?

Comment: JIRA Version - 6.1.3 (War File) & Java JRE -7 O/S - windows 2008 R2 Server, RAM Memory - 8GB Apache -Tomcat Server - 7.0.47